# Eloquent relationship with a where clause

Tags: oop, laravel, eloquent

I need to do a where condition on the `code` field from my intermediate table. My two models are;

```
class Agreement extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'agreements';

  public function clients(){ 
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'client_agreements')->withPivot('start_date', 'expire_date', 'code');
  }
}
```

And;

```
class Client extends Eloquent {
  public function agreements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Agreement', 'client_agreements')->withPivot('start_date', 'expire_date', 'id', 'code');
  }
}
```

My controller is currently;

```
public function show($code, $client_id)
{
    //
    $client = Client::with('agreements')->find($client_id);

    $client_agreement = $client->agreements;

}
```

I think I need to expand the `$client->agreements;` code to include a where condition on the `$code`. I have tried so many different combinations but just keep returning the same Call to undefined method error.

I've tried things like;

```
$client_agreement = $client->agreements->where('code', '=', $code);
$client_agreement = $client->agreements->code->find($code);
$client_agreement = $client->agreements->pivot->code->find($code);
```

I always get the same error. I'm not that great on objects so maybe I'm looking at this all wrong. How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access `->relation()` not `->relation` (which is dynamic property call):

```
$client_agreement = $client->agreements()
                     ->wherePivot('code', '=', $code)
                     ->first();
```